# Git update Play app Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I created a cedar stack from git console and changed the default app name set by Heroku from the Heroku web app. Now when I push the new updates from git, getting an error -App not found.
How to set it right?

Comment: And this error occurs while running `git push heroku master` or similar?

Comment: Yep. How do I make sure that the app name is the same at both- the subdomain at Heroku and the settings in git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your local git config by editing the `.git/config` file and putting the new name.

Your git config should look like this:

```
[remote "heroku"]
  url = git@heroku.com:oldname.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

And the new:

```
[remote "heroku"]
  url = git@heroku.com:newname.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Answer (score 2):

Like [niko_ekito wrote in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18715355/1071311), you can edit the `.git/config` file by hand. But you can also [use Heroku's command line client](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps#updating-git-remotes):

```
$ git remote rm heroku
$ heroku git:remote -a newname
```

Or you can use `git remote set-url`:

```
$ git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:newname.git
```